Where does the quantum state come from, prior to the application of operators?
I'm in the process of trying to learn the basic concepts behind the mathematics of quantum mechanics. I'm having some conceptual confusion, detailed below.
As I understand it, an operator is applied to a quantum state, transforming it into a new quantum state, which reveals more specific information about the quantum system that it represents: for instance, if I want to know the probable positions of a quantum system (in the event of a position measurement) I can apply a position operator to the quantum state, and thereby derive a new quantum state, whose probability amplitudes will represent the desired information (namely, the probable positions in the event of measurement).
My question is, prior to the application of any such operators, what even is the "quantum state"? I understand what "quantum state" would mean after the application of an operator, in that it can be represented as a superposition of the given operator's eigenvectors. But prior to the application of the operator, a quantum state wouldn't seem to have any eigenvectors. So I don't know what its structure is supposed to be, or what the operator is even operating upon.
In explanations of operators and quantum states, they usually jump right in by saying "Suppose a quantum state |Ψ>" and then proceed to apply a first operator to it. But what I want to know is where that initial state |Ψ> came from. How was it derived? What is its structure? Can it be written as a linear combination? What makes it an adequate representative of the quantum system in question (say, of an electron)?

There are an infinite number of possible state functions and arbitrary linear combinations of them will form new states. This is the principle of superposition. The only way a state “arises” is through some process of preparing or measuring a quantum system. Otherwise, states will typically be occupied according to Boltzmann statistics.

The mathematics is mirroring what we are doing in actual experiments: you start with a preparation so that you can reliably and repeatedly get a certain quantum state to start doing experiments with. That is what the maths is also doing; you just start with some arbitrary initial state. All that matters is that it is reasonably stable and repeatable. How precisely you do it, is up to you, and quite immaterial, as long as it is not so awkward that you cannot do the experiment you want to do.

"But prior to the application of the operator, a quantum state wouldn't seem to have any eigenvectors." What are you even saying? This is either trivially wrong, or just makes no sense. First of all, a "state" doesn't "have... eigenvectors;" an operator has eigenvectors.  Second, if the state is $|\Psi\rangle$, then that state is an eigenvector of many different operators. For example, the projection operator $|\Psi\rangle\langle\Psi|$. It seem almost absurd that could somehow accept a "state" "after" application of an operator, but not "before"...

Try this: https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Quantum-Mechanics-David-Griffiths/dp/1107189632

This is not the thrust of your question, but I must point out that "if I want to know the probable positions of a quantum system (in the event of a position measurement) I can apply a position operator to the quantum state" is wrong.  The probabilities are computed from the state that you have (the pre-measurement state): they are the squared amplitudes of the expansion coefficients of the state in the eigenbasis of the operator being measured.  You do not act with the operator on the state to "make a measurement happen".

I don’t quite understand why this question was closed or downvoted that much.  Yes it is full of misconceptions but conceptually it seems entirely legitimate to ask raise these issues.

@ZeroTheHero Raise what issues?

@hft where do quantum state come from

@ZeroTheHero Your answer just describes the usual meaning of a quantum state. I guess that is the answer that OP wanted. But I take issue with the phrase "come from." Saying what something is, is not the same as saying from whence something comes (as if it is handed down from on high or something).

@hft I suppose it’s a matter of semantics but I can see how “comes from” might be ambiguous to some, although it seems fairly clear to me.  In the end I still think the question has merit although (as mentioned) the phraseology is not optimal and may just reflect the OPs confusion with some terminology.

Actually the example of position is not very good because the possible eigenvalues of $\hat x$ are continuous and infinite so let's pick energy (for a bound state).
The state of the system reflects the preparation of this system.  Some experimentalist has a repeatable recipe whereby she or he does something like pass a current through a gas or whatever.  Ignoring for simplicity the possibility of mixed states, the outcome of this procedure is "the state", v.g. some hot gas in a sealed tube.
The experimentalist, possibly with the help of a theorist, then do additional black magic and obtain from the experimental data information about the energy of this state.  This is usually done by measuring moments of some data, v.g. the average energy, the variance of energy etc.  There are devices to measure or ways to infer the energy after each measurement, v.g photocurrent detectors and that sort of stuff: it doesn't matter exactly what is the measurement device.
Then someone comes around and write "the state" as
$$
\vert\psi\rangle = \sum_n c_n \vert E_n\rangle
$$
where $\vert E_n\rangle$ is this state which would give only the one energy $E_n$ if it were prepared (I'm ignoring possible degeneracy) and this someone figures out the various complex coefficients $c_n$ based on the available data.  A key point here is that if you want to describe the outcomes of measuring energies, you use as basis set states of well-defined energies $\{\vert E_n\rangle\}$.  It may or may not be possible in practice to prepare your system so it is ever in a state of definite energy, but at least theoretically these states exists so ideally one could prepare them.
Note that the data may not produce a unique set of $c_n$'s.  For instance, it may be that the data only gives information about the magnitude of each $c_n$'s but not about their phase.  If this is the case, more experimental data - possibly using different measurement devices but using the same preparation - might have to be used.  In fact in general the only way to get information about phases is to get various $\vert E_n\rangle$ to interfere in some ways, and depending on the gear available it may not be possible to actually do this.  For instance, coherent states describe well the statistics of photons in laser light under some specific conditions, but this is based on the distribution of the $\vert c_n\vert^2$ so there could be additional phases in each $c_n$ and we'd still get the same photon distribution.
State reconstruction is in general a nasty business.  You can search for the general topic "quantum state tomography" on GoogleScholar and you're gonna get plenty of hits.
So that's the basic idea: "the state" (at least the initial state before any measurement) is basically some reproducible recipe that produces a physical system mathematically described by a normalized ray in an abstract Hilbert space; the dimension of the Hilbert space is determined by the number of mutually exclusive outcomes of measuring sufficiently many (commuting operators) so we uniquely identify a set of basis states like $\vert E_n\rangle$ (in the simplest case).

Thank you--working through your answer is helping me resolve a number of my misconceptions (which I knew I must have, otherwise I wouldn't be asking the question). I'm realizing that my question was essentially "how do you do quantum state tomography", but I didn't know that's what it's called, lol. (Which is itself striking, seeing how it would seem to be the essential bridge between actual lab experiments and quantum math?)
